# Android ndk: utils/Log.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

am compiling android ndk project but couldn't get it successfully done. It says no such file or directory found for Log header file at main.cpp file. I'm new to android ndk please help. 
here is my android.mk file.

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := user

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

# This is the target being built.
LOCAL_MODULE := libemu

# All of the source files that we will compile.
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    ticks.c \
    main.cpp \
    emulator.cpp

# All of the shared libraries we link against.
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
    libdl \
    libnativehelper \
    libutils

# Static libraries.
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES :=

# Also need the JNI headers.
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
    $(JNI_H_INCLUDE)

# Special compiler flags.
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O3 -fvisibility=hidden

# Don't prelink this library.  For more efficient code, you may want
# to add this library to the prelink map and set this to true. However,
# it's difficult to do this for applications that are not supplied as
# part of a system image.

LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

here is the log

```
"Compile++ arm  : emu <= main.cpp
D:/EclipseWorkspace/NineTendo//jni/main.cpp:2:23: fatal error: utils/Log.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [D:/EclipseWorkspace/NineTendo//obj/local/armeabi/objs/emu/main.o] Error 1
```

any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Voting to close, as the dialog in comments indicates you keep changing the problem you are trying to solve.  Stackoverflow is for *specific* questions, not moving targets.  Primarily it seems that you are in the process of learning how to do development, and should be relying more on the examples as BitBank suggested.

Answer (score 2):

This error started to show up in NDK version R9x. You need to declare the API version number in your **Application.mk** file. Here's how it looks to define a minimum API level of 8:

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

The **Application.mk** file should live alongside your **Android.mk** file in the JNI directory. Here's a sample from one of my projects:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
APP_CFLAGS += -O2
LOCAL_ARM_MODE  := arm
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,very much appreciated :). But my project don't have application.mk file. Should I create new one if yes then where ?

Comment: I build from the command line using NDK-BUILD. I'm not sure how the project files are managed if you're using the automatic build from within Eclipse.

Comment: I'v followed this tutorial to build ndk project http://www.jayway.com/2011/10/13/getting-started-with-android-ndk/

Comment: I've written your code in Android.mk file,but still there is same error.

Comment: The information above is for the application.mk file, not the android.mk file.

Comment: oh,yes. I've created new application.mk in jni folder and wrote that code in it but still there is no luck. Log has same error :(

Comment: Are you sure the file you want to include is "utils/log.h" and not "android/log.h"? Check your ndk directory to see where it's located.

Comment: I've tried to write android/log.h instead of util/Log.h but it gives me same error for next header file which nativehelper/jni.h If i'll write jni.h instead of nativehelper/jni.h then previous error won't come but new ones which says " In function 'jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM*, void*)' "

Comment: I would suggest starting your work from a working sample NDK application and then you won't have to doubt both your setup and your code.

Comment: yeah,it is a sample project but am unable to compile. I've created new project and wrote c code then used it. It run successfully then i've picked up an open source project for learning but couldn't compile :( here is its link http://code.google.com/p/androidnes/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FNesoid%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fandroidemu%2Fnes%253Fstate%253Dclosed

Comment: BitBank, I've a list of gaming emulators and I want to build and run them all. If you can help me, I'll pay you. I've open job at odesk :)

Comment: I'm the author of SmartGear on Google Play. Contact me to discuss game emulators (bitbank@pobox.com).

Comment: `APP_PLATFORM` is for **target** api level, not **minimum**.